# How to migrate your dbt project from dbt-postgres to dbt-databricks

Tags: database, postgresql, databricks, dbt

I have my my dbt-project configured and running for dbt-postgres. Is there an easy way to port it to dbt- databricks without having to rewrite the models.
Context: I am building a dbt demo on postgres, databricks and Azure SQL for my organization to see how well it fit our environments.
What I’ve already tried : I have successfully running pipelines on dbt-postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dbt handles the DDL/DML boilerplate; for `select` statements, postgres and sparkSQL/databricks aren't that far off, but you will have to make some tweaks to the models to get things running, and you'll want to take advantage of some of the config in databricks, like partitioning.

One way to ease this transition is to use dbt's [cross-database macros](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/cross-database-macros), which standardize syntax for functions like `datediff`, which can vary between dialects.

Another option, if your models don't contain much jinja, would be to use [`sqlglot`](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot) to transpile between dialects.

If you have the same data in postgres and databricks, you can use datafold's [`data-diff`](https://github.com/datafold/data-diff) to compare the results of the modeled data between datastores, to confirm you ported everything correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Fyi databricks is coming out with lateral aliases, which will ease a lot of the problems.
https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-name-resolution.html
Databricks Runtime 12.2 and above

Comment: Please share more details. How does your answer even relate to the given question?

Comment: We migrated from postgres to databricks a few months ago. 
The biggest pain of migrating from postgres to databricks for me was having to rewrite all the lateral aliases (only solution was either making a lot of with statements or declaring them as variables). They just recently came out with support for this, so if he was struggling with this part of the port, making sure he is on runtime 12.2 or above might save a lot of effort.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, share what **exactly** needs to be done. An answer should be self-contained, there should be no need to visit any external website to understand it